# Finding the largest number in an array using assembly code?

Tags: arrays, assembly

So I'm trying to figure out how to write a program that will find the largest number in the array but it needs to use assembly meaning that I have a limited set of commands (i.e. add, subtract, jump if 0 and jump if less then zero). Here is what I have so far:

```
C00A 000    jmp     start   skip over the variables
0001 001    dw      a[0]
0002 002    dw      a[1]
0003 003    dw      a[2]
0004 004    dw      a[3]
0005 005    dw      a[4]
0006 006    dw      a[5]
0000 007    dw  
0000 008            leave space for changes
0000 009
1000 00A start          so now what?
```

I have the array initialized with a couple of hard coded values and now I need to write a type of loop that will find the largest one among them. This is what I have figured out so far:

```
load a[0]  load first value
sub  a[1]  subtract second value
jmpl       the result is negative (meaning a[1]>a[0]) jump somewhere
```

I understand the underlying philosophy but I just don't know how to create a system that will "loop" until it find the max value.

Comment: You're thinking about the wrong thing. That is to say, you dont loop until you found the biggest element - you loop until you examined all elements. Also, you should edit your question to include the CPU you're targeting.

Answer (score 1):

This is basically what you need to code in assembly language.

```
 load  a[0]    ;load first value
 sub   a[1]    ;subtract second value
 jmpl  IsBigger1
 load  a[0]    ;reload first value
 store a[1]    ;replace second value
IsBigger1:

 load  a[1]    ;load second value
 sub   a[2]    ;subtract third value
 jmpl  IsBigger2
 load  a[1]    ;reload second value
 store a[2]    ;replace third value
IsBigger2:
```

I've shown 2 blocks of code. You should add 3 such blocks and then you'll find the max value in the last element of the array a[5].
This is an unrolled version of the loop that you need. Because you didn't specify the architecture I can't possibly suggest the necessary instructions to turn this into a real loop. Your "limited set of commands" doesn't even mention `load`.

EDIT

It's a pitty this architecture forces us to write self modifying code.
Nevertheless it was great fun writing my first IBCM program!

```
addr    dw 1
count   dw 5
one     dw 1
isload  dw 3000
isstore dw 4000
issub   dw 6000

again   load    count
        sub     one
        jmpl    exit
        store   count
        load    isload
        add     addr
        store   a
        load    issub
        add     addr
        add     one
        store   b
a       nop
b       nop
        jmpl    bigger
        load    isload
        add     addr
        store   c
        load    isstore
        add     addr
        add     one
        store   d
c       nop
d       nop
bigger  load    addr
        add     one
        store   addr
        jmp     again
exit    halt
```

Comment: It's in a language called IBCM and we have set of jumps that work if the result is 0 or less then 0 and they can jump to a specific location in memory.

Comment: @IsabelAlphonse I've added an example program.